# Javascript Form

Tags: javascript, function

I have a quick question.  I am learning how to make a registration form using javascript and found this link very helpful.

http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-sample-registration-form-validation.php

I understand everything in the code except for this line in the html page...

```
<body onload="document.registration.userid.focus();">
```

I know it is saying that when the page is loaded run this javascript function, but I don't understand what each part does.  If someone could please explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means when the page is loaded set the focus on to the `userid` field in the form names `registration` in the `document`

You can use

```
document.getElementById("userid").focus()
```

This asks to select the field named `userid` in the `document`. So we can make it free of Form name

Comment: Ah! So that is why I found little information on it.  The fool who wrote it is an old timer.  What exactly does the 'focus()' part do though?

Comment: The element does not have an ID!

Comment: The edit you made is incorrect, it does not find by id, the element has a name not an id and so using getElementsByName("userid")[0] to get the element is more appropriate, however using the method described in original post if no id is set is still most appropriate.

Its nothing to do with old school, its still very much an accepted way of doing things.

Comment: focus just set the focus (cursor) in to the specified control (textbox). Please note that to use `getElementById` you should have `ID` set like `ID="userid"`

Answer (score 1):

This is the direct way to "walk the DOM." Starting from the top (document) you then select successive elements by `name`. The form's `name` is `registration` and the element's `name` is 
 `userid`. The call to `.focus()` places the cursor in that field so that the user can begin typing immediately when the page loads instead of manually highlighting the field.

Comment: I like the change from "old" to "direct".

Comment: @JonTaylor inspired by you, sir. jQuery has softened me.

Comment: Ha, I agree jQuery often makes you forget the different ways of doing things.  Lets face it, jQuery is awesome.